# Get semicolon which are not enclosed in parenthesis using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my text, how to get semicolon which are not enclosed in parenthesis using RegExp.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Web0S; Linux/SmartTV) AppleWebKit/538.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Large Screen Safari/538.2 LG Browser/7.00.00(LGE; 65UF8500-UB; 04.00.45; 1; DTV_W15U); webOS.TV-2015; LG NetCast.TV-2013 Compatible (LGE, 65UF8500-UB, wireless)
```

Comment: an example of what you want to capture?

Comment: how do i get  semicolon those are not enclosed in paranthesis,please let me knw

Comment: an example would be helpful what you want to extract from the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the parenthesis with an empty string. You have multiple parenthesis in your text so it's probably best to use a non-greedy regex like `\(.+?\)`.

```
var text = "Mozilla/5.0 (Web0S; Linux/SmartTV) AppleWebKit/538.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Large Screen Safari/538.2 LG Browser/7.00.00(LGE; 65UF8500-UB; 04.00.45; 1; DTV_W15U); webOS.TV-2015; LG NetCast.TV-2013 Compatible (LGE, 65UF8500-UB, wireless)";
var output = text.replace(/\(.+?\)/g, "");
console.log(output);
```

The non-greedy regex selects the smallest chunks possible, instead of making a selection from the first to last parenthesis.

You may run into trouble when your text contains parenthesis inside each other, but I'll try to edit that in.

Comment: but how can we do this  by using regex

Comment: how do i get semicolon those are not enclosed in paranthesis,please let me knw

Comment: This is using a regex. If you also want a possible semicolon after the parenthesis then you can use `/\(.+?\)(;)?/g`

Comment: thank  u fr this...but i want to get the semicolon which are not enclosed in paranthesis..by using ur answer i get the semicolons enclosed in paranthesis..plzz check it once

Comment: You edited your question 3 hours ago. First you were asking for the text in parenthesis.

Comment: am sorry..plzz let me knw the solutionj fr this one

Comment: @reshma: You could still use this answer to strip out the parentheses, and then parse for semi-colons as you would normally. Looking at the edit history of your question, it seems you were trying to ask about semicolons initially, but it was edited out of your title by someone else - probably because the wording of your title was very sloppy. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the bit where it says "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important!" Even if English isn't your first language, avoid speaking like a 12-year-old texting.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Web0S; Linux/SmartTV) AppleWebKit/538.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Large Screen Safari/538.2 LG Browser/7.00.00(LGE; 65UF8500-UB; 04.00.45; 1; DTV_W15U); webOS.TV-2015; LG NetCast.TV-2013 Compatible (LGE, 65UF8500-UB, wireless)';
var regex = /\(.*?\)|([^\W_]+[^\s-]*)/g;
var arr = [];
var newstr = '';
var match = regex.exec(str);

while (match != null) {
    if( match[1] != null ) arr.push(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(str);
}

if (arr.length > 0) {
   for (key in arr) newstr = newstr+ " " + arr[key];
}
console.log(newstr);
```